# Flutter: How to convert URI to File?

Tags: flutter

I want to convert path "content://media/external/images/media/138501" to File and set in the Image.

Code:

```
File imageFile = File("content://media/external/images/media/138501");
```

is not working on:

```
DecorationImage(image: ExactAssetImage(imageFile.path),fit: BoxFit.fill)
```

Comment: The easiet way to do is to better convert the File to byte array and then show that using Image.memory.
To convert the file to byte array follow this link (in Java) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039672/android-how-to-read-file-in-bytes

To show the byte array in flutter, follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516310/sending-bitmap-to-flutter-from-android-platform

Answer (score 3):

You can use [uri_to_file](https://pub.dev/packages/uri_to_file) package. It supports content:// URI.

Simple to use (Updated)

```
import 'package:uri_to_file/uri_to_file.dart';

try {
  String uriString = 'content://sample.txt';

  // Don't pass uri parameter using [Uri] object via uri.toString().
  // Because uri.toString() changes the string to lowercase which causes this package to misbehave

  // If you are using uni_links package for deep linking purpose.
  // Pass the uri string using getInitialLink() or linkStream

  File file = await toFile(uriString);
} on UnsupportedError catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
} on IOException catch (e) {
  print(e);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

then you can use this file as you want

**Important note**

Don't pass uri value like this

```
File file = await toFile(uri.toString());
```

Use like this if you are using [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) package for deep linking purpose. Use getInitialLink() or linkStream

```
String? uriString = await getInitialLink();
if (uriString != null) {
  File file = await toFile(uriString);
}

linkStream.listen((uriString) async {
  if (uriString != null) {
    File file = await toFile(uriString!);
  }
});
```

This will not modify the uri string as we are not using uri.toString()

So this package will work fine

Working example:
[Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBbUk.gif)

For more details: [uri_to_file](https://medium.com/@nikhil.koshty/flutter-convert-content-uri-to-file-a49e3dfe3d8f)

Comment: worked for me, having trouble with flutter_absolute_path. This solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: Got error: Unable to fetch filename.

Comment: Hi @PromlertLovichit.
"Got error: Unable to fetch filename"

This issue is now fixed also updated the answer
You can use latest uri_to_file: 0.2.0

Just make sure you pass the uri string value properly as given in the updated answer

Comment: Unluckily this project seems to be no longer maintained. I guess you are the maintainer, @Nikhil ?
Merging this would be great: https://github.com/Nikhil1999/uri-to-file/pull/9

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Absolute path](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_absolute_path) plugin.

```
final filePath = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(uriString);
```

and then show the image by using `Image.file`:

```
Image.file(
    File(filePath),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of flutter_absolute_path  package.
flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6 In pubsec.yaml

To convert file path from this format : `“content://media/external/images/media/5275”` To
`"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_00124.jpg”`

```
final filePath = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath("Any path 
   here");

File tempFile = File(filePath);

    if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
      //add your logic here.
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

define your `URL`:

`final url = "Your Image Url";`

then convert the `Image Url` to `File` in `flutter` :

`XFile _xFile = XFile(url);`

Done.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-io/File-class.html) you can use the **fromUri** constructor: `File.fromUri(Uri uri)`.

Your case:

```dart
File imageFile = File.fromUri("content://media/external/images/media/138501");
```

Comment: Very nice! Finally

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`Image.file`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.file.html) constructor.

```
DecorationImage(
  image: Image.file(File("content://media/external/images/media/138501")),
  fit: BoxFit.fill
)
```

Please take a note: On Android, this may require the `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: I tried the same, But code did not work. I took "content://medi..." path from Asset.dart object and tried to convert into file.

It seems flutter does not accept converting above URL directly to File.