# Convert a UInt8List to Image in flutter/dart-ui

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this scenario where I have to get a UInt8List from an image like that:

```
List stuff = image.toByteData().buffer.asUInt8List()
```

Do some manipulations and get back to a [Image](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html).

I've tried the following:

```
List stuff = image.toByteData().buffer.asUInt8List()
ui.decodeImageFromList(stuff, (image){
  // do stuff with image
});
```

But I keep getting this Exception:

```
E/flutter (10201): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/painting/codec.cc(97)] Failed decoding image. Data is either invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.
E/flutter (10201): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(186)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
...
```

Take notice that even without any changes in the List the exception is thrown. How can I make the list have a encodable format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ui.Image` can turn itself into an RGBA bitmap (or PNG), but cannot convert itself back from a bitmap. (The reason for this is that there isn't any way to tell the image codec things like the color depth, geometry, etc.) The solution is to add a BMP file header onto the front of your bitmap, where you can describe those missing things, then pass that to `instantiateImageCodec`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315442/use-ui-decodeimagefromlist-to-display-an-image-created-from-a-list-of-bytes/51316489#51316489), but note that in that case the bitmap in question had a strange packed color map. In your case of 32 bit RGBA, the header would be even simpler.

Comment: After this answer, I started to work on something to make this easier. I'm converting Uint8List into Image with Bitmap, a package I've made. Thanks.

https://github.com/renancaraujo/bitmap/

Answer (score 58):

You can use memory image as given below, for the direct byte rendering

```
child: Image.memory(Uint8List bytes);
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Uint8List that are generated from a `ui.Image` instance

Answer (score 9):

You can use MemoryImage class to convert a Uint8List to image.

`var _image = MemoryImage(image);`

You can find more details about this class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/MemoryImage-class.html)

Answer (score 5):

use this.

```
static Future<ui.Image> bytesToImage(Uint8List imgBytes) async{
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(imgBytes);
    ui.FrameInfo frame;
    try {
      frame = await codec.getNextFrame();
    } finally {
      codec.dispose();
    }
    return frame.image;
  }
```

Comment: need to be import `import 'dart:ui' as ui;`

Comment: You need to call `codec.dispose()` before `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tested code for you.

```
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final pathOfImage = await File('${directory.path}/legendary.png').create();
    final Uint8List bytes = stuff.buffer.asUint8List();
    await pathOfImage.writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

> final Uint8List bytes = stuff.buffer.asUint8List();

Here, **stuff** refers to the Uint8List that should be converted to an image.

Answer (score 1):

this method worked for me, got the reference from another answer to a similar kind of problem at stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59443221/12931178)

```
Future<ui.Image> loadImage(Uint8List img) async {
    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(img, (ui.Image img) {
      return completer.complete(img);
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
```