# Flutter - convert and resize asset image to dart ui image

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I'm attempting to take an asset image, resize the image to an arbitrary width and height, and convert the image to a dart ui image so that I can draw the image on a canvas using the [drawImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawImage.html) method. This so I can adjust the image for different screen sizes.

However I'm running into an issue resizing the image. I've attempted several different approaches but the best I've managed is to either draw the correct image data with the image cropped instead of resized, the data invalidated (incorrect decoding static) at the correct size, or the correct image data while failing to resize the image.

My named imports are

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' as widgets;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as image;
```

Some of my attempts are as follows:

Displays the correct image data while failing to adjust the size:

```
Future<ui.Image> loadUiImage(String imageAssetPath) async {
  widgets.Image widgetsImage = widgets.Image.asset(imageAssetPath, scale: 0.5);
  Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
  widgetsImage.image
    .resolve(widgets.ImageConfiguration(size: ui.Size(10, 10)))
    .addListener(widgets.ImageStreamListener((widgets.ImageInfo info, bool _){
      completer.complete(info.image);
    }));
  return completer.future;
}
```

Incorrectly crops the images without resizing, though the image data is correct:

```
Future<ui.Image> loadUiImage(String imageAssetPath) async {
  final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(imageAssetPath);
  List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
  image.Image iconImage = image.Image.fromBytes(100, 100, bytes);
  final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
  ui.decodeImageFromList(image.decodePng(image.encodePng(iconImage)).getBytes(), (ui.Image img) {
    return completer.complete(img);
  });
  return completer.future;
}
```

Invalidated image data, correctly resized image:

```
Future<ui.Image> loadUiImage(String imageAssetPath) async {
  final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(imageAssetPath);
  List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
  image.Image iconImage = image.Image.fromBytes(100, 100, bytes);
  final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
  ui.decodeImageFromList(image.encodePng(iconImage), (ui.Image img) {
    return completer.complete(img);
  });
  return completer.future;
}
```

I've also attempted to utilize the Bitmap method used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315442/use-ui-decodeimagefromlist-to-display-an-image-created-from-a-list-of-bytes/51316489#51316489), but hit an error in the provided function

> Failed assertion: line 274 pos 12: 'bitmap.length == size': is not true

in my attempted use after trying to resize the image.

I'd greatly appreciate any help in solving this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Been a while since was able to work on this side project, but was able to accomplish the conversion and resize using the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image#-readme-tab-) package:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as image;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Future<ui.Image> getUiImage(String imageAssetPath, int height, int width) async {
  final ByteData assetImageByteData = await rootBundle.load(imageAssetPath);
  image.Image baseSizeImage = image.decodeImage(assetImageByteData.buffer.asUint8List());
  image.Image resizeImage = image.copyResize(baseSizeImage, height: height, width: width);
  ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(image.encodePng(resizeImage));
  ui.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
  return frameInfo.image;
}
```

Comment: I have the following error with 'ui.instantiateImageCodec(image.encodePng(resizeImage));' : The argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ys.commerciale/process-and-show-an-image-in-flutter-aebb0054ce94

Shows how to handle the bytes to appropriately encode/decode to translate from img.Image to ui.Image.

Comment: ```
Future<ui.Image> imgImageToUiImage(img.Image image) async{
  ui.ImmutableBuffer buffer = await
    ui.ImmutableBuffer.fromUint8List(
        image.getBytes(format: img.Format.rgba));
  ui.ImageDescriptor id = ui.ImageDescriptor.raw(
      buffer,
      height: image.height,
      width: image.width,
      pixelFormat: ui.PixelFormat.rgba8888);
  ui.Codec codec = await id.instantiateCodec(
      targetHeight: image.height,
      targetWidth: image.width);
  ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
  ui.Image uiImage = fi.image;
  return uiImage;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve this without using the `image` package:

```dart
Future<ui.Image> getUiImage(String imageAssetPath, int height, int width) async {
  final ByteData assetImageByteData = await rootBundle.load(imageAssetPath);
  final codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(
    assetImageByteData.buffer.asUint8List(),
    targetHeight: height,
    targetWidth: width,
  );
  final image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
}
```