# How to convert RGB pixmap to ui.Image in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-ffi

Currently I have a Uint8List, formatted like [R,G,B,R,G,B,...] for all the pixels of the image. And of course I have its width and height.

I found `decodeImageFromPixels` while searching but it only takes RGBA/BGRA format. I converted my pixmap from RGB to RGBA and this function works fine.

However, my code now looks like this:

```dart
Uint8List rawPixel = raw.value.asTypedList(w * h * channel);
List<int> rgba = [];
for (int i = 0; i < rawPixel.length; i++) {
  rgba.add(rawPixel[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
      rgba.add(0);
    }
}

Uint8List rgbaList = Uint8List.fromList(rgba);

Completer<Image> c = Completer<Image>();
decodeImageFromPixels(rgbaList, w, h, PixelFormat.rgba8888, (Image img) {
  c.complete(img);
});
```

I have to make a new list(waste in space) and iterate through the entire list(waste in time).

This is too inefficient in my opinion, is there any way to make this more elegant? Like add a new `PixelFormat.rgb888`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than calling `add` it might be faster to directly create a `Uint8List` of length `w * h * 4` and use your for loop to copy from `rawPixel` to `rgba` indexing into each array. `decodeImageFromPixels` ultimately ends up creating a `Codec` and that understands all sort of BMP formats (including RGB888). You could adapt this answer to prepend a BMP header and simply call `instantiateImageCodec`. The BMP parsing is presumably fast and optimized. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315442/use-ui-decodeimagefromlist-to-display-an-image-created-from-a-list-of-bytes/51316489#51316489

Comment: @RichardHeap Thanks! Now I'm going to live with padding RGB to RGBA for now. If the performance hurts I will try to switch to bmp as  you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find that this loop is faster as it doesn't keep appending to the list and then copy it at the end.

```
  final rawPixel = raw.value.asTypedList(w * h * channel);
  final rgbaList = Uint8List(w * h * 4); // create the Uint8List directly as we know the width and height

  for (var i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
    final rgbOffset = i * 3;
    final rgbaOffset = i * 4;
    rgbaList[rgbaOffset] = rawPixel[rgbOffset]; // red
    rgbaList[rgbaOffset + 1] = rawPixel[rgbOffset + 1]; // green
    rgbaList[rgbaOffset + 2] = rawPixel[rgbOffset + 2]; // blue
    rgbaList[rgbaOffset + 3] = 255; // a
  }
```

An alternative is to prepend the array with a BMP header by adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315442/use-ui-decodeimagefromlist-to-display-an-image-created-from-a-list-of-bytes/51316489#51316489) (though it would simpler as there would be no palette) and passing that bitmap to `instantiateImageCodec` as that code is presumably highly optimized for parsing bitmaps.

Comment: I think there's a typo: Multiply by 4 instead of adding right?: 
`final rgbaList = Uint8List(w * h * 4);` Other than that, this is very neat and concise ;)